# Meaning of たんか when used in a sentence or phrase?

Tags: translation, meaning, manga

i came across this phrase "酒飲めたんか" and i know that 酒 is probably referring to alcohol and 飲め probably means 'drinking' but the phrase　’たんか’ does not give me any result when i tried to search for it.
I'm just guessing here but is this a slang for "I cannot drink anymore"/"I've finished drinking (from my cup)"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Kansai, we say 「～～たんか？」 to mean 「～～たのか？」.

「酒飲めたんか？」(Kansai) means 「酒は(orを)飲めたのか？」(Standard), "Could you drink / Were you able to drink sake/alcohol?"

(As you know, 飲めた is the past potential form of 飲む.)

Comment: i didn't realize it was specifically here in Kansai area... no other areas have that expression?

Comment: oh i see! i didn't take into context that it might be written in the Kansai dialect at all! thank you so much for the clarification!

Comment: @ericfromabeno そうですね・・ I think it's probably used in 四国, 中国地方, and maybe 九州 too.. I'm not sure though. たぶん。。